# Internally compensated opamp for 5V/V or more

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, single-supply-op-amp

I am using opamp for some signal conditioning circuit. I want to use opamp as voltage follower. It is mentioned in the Opamp datasheet that opamp is internallly compensated for 5/5V, 10V/V, or more etc.

I have read the concept of internal compensation of opamp for unity gain. I am doubtful about internal compensation for 5 or 10 gain.

Does it mean that I have to externally set at least 5 gain with feedback resistor? i can't connect in follower configuration?

or does it mean even if i connect in voltage follower configuration (inverting terminal to output) with unity gain, Vout=5*Vin?

Answer (score 6):

The gain of an op-amp is set by the feedback network.

If you have an amplifier compensated for minimum gain of 5 and apply feedback that results in less gain, phase margin will be inadequate and you run the risk of oscillation, especially at unity gain.

For example, the [LMH6624](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6624.pdf?ts=1616149602531&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FsearchTerm%253DLMH6624) is decompensated so a minimum gain \$|A_V| \ge 10\$ is required for stability. You can see the gain peaking as a result for relatively low magnitude gains that approach the minimum:

[image]

Comment: The practical import being, if you want to use it at lower gain, you'll have to design an external compensation network to keep it stable. It's usually easier to find an internally compensated version of the same opamp, like the 741 (unity gain compensated) vs the 748 (uncompensated, faster).

Comment: @BrianDrummond Though a 741 might not be the best choice as a replacement for the 1.8GHz < 1nV/sqrt(Hz) noise LMH6624.

Comment: Hah! I wasn't suggesting the USE of a 741! It's just the classic example of the same opamp available with(741)/without(748) compensation. I don't offhand know if there is a similar (better compensated) family member for the LMH6624.